# I am not able to boot Ubuntu desktop in Raspberry Pi 4b through SD card

Tags: software-installation

I tried many times but I am unable to boot Ubuntu in Raspberry Pi 4b getting below error every time I boot. Can anyone help with the solution, please?

```
ERROR:
10.8629541 zsunp: compressor zstd not available, using default 120 
10.8806301 zauap: zpool z3fold not available, using default zbud 
Thu Jan 1 00:00:02 UTC 1970 
GROWROOT: CHANGED: partition 2 start-526336 old: size 17689504 end-18215840 new: size-61807583 end-62333919
```

[image: error]